# Line Graph in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph

This is my app screen shot Im parse dynamic data for graph Im not using graphs on past please help me in advance

[image]

Comment: use this library...https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts

Comment: this question is incomprehensible. find someone who actually speaks English and ask him to help you ask a coherent, sensible question.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create graphs using `Core Graphics`.

See this amazing tutorial on Raywenderlich.com website:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/90693/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-2